# How to fetch relations for a given user in parse-server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Trying to fetch relations for a user via the parse REST api

I have a class called `Interest` containing simple text fields `(music, art, movies, etc)`

My query:

```
/classes/Interest/?where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"User","objectId":"<userObjectId>"},"key":"interest"}}
```

I would expect this to return those `interest` associated with the given user `objectID`. I keep getting an empty array.

When I try a similar query against a class that is not the reserved `User` it performs as expected.

Am I missing something or might this be a bug? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. If using the `User` class, you need to add an underscore as its a reserved class. `_User`